# How to filter a angular table row with a second table row selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have two angular tables using the same controller but on separate views. Table A has a list of Jobs. Table B has a list of ChangeOrders. When a user clicks on a Job on table A, table B needs to only show the ChangeOrders that go with that Job. Every ChangeOrder has a JobId as the foreign key.

Table A

```
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover" ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true">
                    <tr ng-repeat="job in $data" class="pointer">
                        <td  data-title="'Job Number'" sortable="'JobNumber'" filter="{ 'JobNumber': 'text' }">{{job.JobNumber}}</td>
                        <td  data-title="'Job Name'" sortable="'JobName'" filter="{ 'JobName': 'text' }">{{job.JobName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Table B

```
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover" ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" >
        <tr ng-repeat="job in $data"  class=" pointer">
            <td ng-click="editChangeOrderModal(job)" data-title="'CO Number'" sortable="'ChangeOrderNumber'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderNumber': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderNumber}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO Date'" sortable="'ChangeOrderDate'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderDate': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderDate | date : date : shortDate}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO Name'" sortable="'ChangeOrderName'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderName': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderName}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO Description'" sortable="'ChangeOrderDescription'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderDescription': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderDescription}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO Amount'" sortable="'ChangeOrderAmount'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderAmount': 'text' }">${{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderAmount | number : fractionSize}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO ApprovedDate'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedDate'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedDate': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderApprovedDate | date : date : shortDate}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO ApprovedAmount'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedAmount'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedAmount': 'text' }">${{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderApprovedAmount | number : fractionSize}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO ApprovedNumber'" sortable="'ChangeOrderApprovedNumber'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderApprovedNumber': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderApprovedNumber}}</td>
            <td data-title="'CO Attn'" sortable="'ChangeOrderAttn'" filter="{ 'ChangeOrderAttn': 'text' }">{{job.ChangeOrders[0].ChangeOrderAttn}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though those two views have the same controller, they have different instances of that controller so they're not sharing any data. The proper way to share data between controllers is using [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) or the $rootScope.

You'll need to set the selected job when clicking the row.

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs" ng-click="selectJob(job)">
    <!-- job stuff here -->
</tr>
```

In the controller you'll need to set that clicked job in a service (or for this example the $rootScope)

```
$scope.selectJob = function(job) {
  $rootScope.selectedJob = job;
};
```

Then you'll need a function to get the currently selected job (so you can display the change orders for that).

```
$scope.selectedJob = $scope.selectedJob = function() {
  return $rootScope.selectedJob;
};
```

For your change orders table, the ng-repeat just needs to go off of that selected job.

```
<tr ng-repeat="changeOrder in selectedJob().changeOrders">
    <td>{{changeOrder.name}}</td>
    <td>{{changeOrder.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now selecting a job row will show the corresponding change orders in the other table.  I put together a small example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9SiXPSx6gu5vCbdeztG?p=preview). Let me know if this helps you out!